# Visual Studio 2012 intermittent lockup

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2012 intermittently locks up on me. I notice that devenv.exe jumps to 50% CPU utilization. The CPU stays at this level for a few minutes and then drops. While its at 50% utilization I can still use the IDE. However, intermittently it stops responding (as though it was performing some sort of background process). It only lasts for a few seconds.

Also this happens when debugging.

I'm running under Windows 7 and I'm using Telerik controls.

I've disabled add-ins and extensions and have had no success.

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I haven't checked this post in a while. Just wanted to let anyone who reads this that I figured it out.

For some reason in VS2012, if you leave the web.config file open, VS (or maybe IIS) must be doing something in the background and causes VS to hang. This is weird, because I never had the problem in previous versions of VS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Telerik Just Code? I had to disable it because it was consuming way too much memory. To disable it you have to start VS as an administrator (right click on VS icon and run as administrator) . Then select Tools/Add In Manager and uncheck start up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is almost a year old but I'm trying to post this answer in a few places since this is what was causing my ills: I had the Data Sources toolbox open in Visual Studio 2012. Once I closed that, it seemed to eliminate the lengthy delays when switching windows. You may also want to close Server Manager if you don't need it open.